# elements to the array do not return the current state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For example, I add 10 components.

When I click the show logs button on the 5th line, the first 4 components appear on the console.

But even if I click the button on the 5th line, I want all the components to appear on the console.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { observer } from "mobx-react-lite";

function App() {
  const [component, setComponent] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {});

  const Test = observer(() => {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>
          Test <button onClick={testFunction("myFunction"))}>Show logs</button>
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  });

  function testFunction(a) {
    console.log(component);
    console.log(a)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {component.map((Input, index) => (
        <Input key={index} />
      ))}
      <button onClick={() => setComponent([...component, Test])}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-useeffect-forked-7q15no

Comment: Hey tom, has the `observer` method got anything to do with this? if not, I would remove it to help people answer your question

Comment: Hey @alextrastero yes it is related.

Comment: ok, when you add a component to an array, the function is already bound to return a value, even if you add more components to that array, the first component of the array will always log the same result.

Comment: hi @alextrastero so is there any trick to overcome this?

Comment: Take a look at this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-useeffect-forked-syo2sf?file=/src/index.js). Is this what you want to achieve?

Comment: Thank you @SinanYaman example helped me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the Observer is getting a previous version of component, which is not consistent with the updated component. In cases like this, useEffect is usually a better option as it updates instantly instead of asynchronously. Refer to the code below which is working:

The updater simply makes the useEffect hook run which logs the latest value of component. The onClick now simply updates the updater.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { observer } from "mobx-react-lite";

function App() {
  const [component, setComponent] = useState([]);
  const [updater, setUpdater] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {console.log(component)}, [updater]);

  const Test = observer(() => {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>
          Test <button onClick={() => setUpdater(updater + 1)}>Show logs</button>
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  });

  return (
    <div>
      {component.map((Input, index) => (
        <Input key={index} />
      ))}
      <button onClick={() => setComponent([...component, Test])}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Hey thanks for answer and comments but where can I trigger testFunction?

Comment: You don't need it here. The onClick on the observer should update the "updater". In the useEfect hook I have written updater in the [ ]. This means that whenever updater is updated the code in the useEffect hook runs.